ADO.NET Firebird remote backup-restore file cleanup
I am using Firebird with ADO.NET provider to backup/restore a database on a remote server.
This is creating a temporary .bak file on the server which I'd like to delete after completion.
Is there a way to manage remote files on firebird via ADO.NET provider?
I know create is possible as FbConnection.CreateDatabase creates the DB file if it does not exist. There is an option on restore to overwrite an existing database too. What about deleting a database or a backup file?

Are you sure that you're talking about a temporary file, and not the actual backup file? If it is temporary file, it should get cleaned up automatically (possibly only when the Firebird process exits), and otherwise you should report a bug. However, I guess it is a backup file (e.g. you yourself used the .bak extension when specifying the backup file), then Firebird does not provide anything to delete backup files. You need to use the normal file management tools of the server to do that.

There is no point to perform backup if you don't want to keep backup file. Regular backup-restore (especially with replacing of original database) is a very bad idea from any point of view.

Ok answer is - not possible.
Backup-restore has several usages, reducing file size after DB purge is one. In my case, I do it to "split" databases - one having old data and a new one with only "current" data. I know it's a bit specific but it does make absolute sense in my context!

Usually people use replication for this task.

Firebird, and by extension the Firebird .NET provider, provides no mechanism to delete backup files. You will need to use the file management tools of the OS for that.
